# Big DB call + parse in Java VS many db calls

Tags: java, mysql

I have a project that counts instances of specific conditions within a MySQL table for a dashboard.  It started out simple, but after a couple of "can you add..." requests, I'm up to 86 different queries in my program.  I expect more "can you add..." requests in the future for it.

For efficiency's sake, would it be better/faster to query the data in bulk to Java then do the sorting/counting there, or continue with individual queries?

The table is small, right now <300 rows and I don't see it ever climbing above 900 rows, if that matters.

Comment: Is the data manipulated by the same dashboard, or updated in realtime? If not, you can chose to cache the data in your application.

Comment: @ImJustACowLol it's updated in realtime.

Comment: Another approach: have a database trigger on the detail table, where the trigger does the aggregating and updates a summary table.  Your app gets the handful of summary records.  Part II: since the data is updated real time push a notification from the database whenever the summary table changes (instead of your app having to continually poll the database).

Comment: @AndrewS I'm a much better Java programmer than I am a database person, unfortunately.

Comment: Without knowing the specific queries, and how frequently you run them, it's not possible to answer this question generally. The most general thing I can advise is that if the 86+ queries still get your data results in a satisfactory time, it's probably better to run many queries, just for reasons of modular coding.

Comment: @BillKarwin  All the queries are variations of "SELECT count(*) where [condition A] and [condition B] and [condition C]".  It's set to run every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All the queries are variations of "SELECT count(*) where [condition A] and [condition B] and [condition C]". It's set to run every 5 minutes.

A tip for these sorts of queries: A SUM() of expressions that are either 1 or 0 is the same as a COUNT() of the rows where the expression is true. This is a handy MySQL-specific trick (other SQL implementations don't treat true/false as the same as 1/0).

```
SELECT
  SUM(<condition A>) AS count_A,
  SUM(<condition B>) AS count_B,
  SUM(<condition C>) AS count_C,
  ...
FROM mytable
```

This lets you run one query to scan the table once, while "counting" the rows with different conditions.

Its pretty straightforward once you know the trick about SUM(), and easy to add more columns to the query to get other types of counts.